# Uno platform flyout menu sub item placed outside visible region on Andorid

Tags: uno-platform

When using **MenuFlyoutSubItem** the sub items pane is placed outside visible area on Android:

Android emulator showing sub items not visible :

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="More"/>
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedRight">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Sub Items">
                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Sub Item 1"/>
                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Sub Item 2"/>
                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Sub Item 2"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue [has been fixed in the previews](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/7184) of Uno Platform 3.11, where the layout of popups was incorrectly detecting the bounds of the current window.

You can try the preview bits by checking the experimental box in your nuget package managed and install the latest `3.11.0-dev.XX` packages.

Comment: thanks that fixed the issue. I updated nuget package Uno.UI to 3.11.0-dev.310 and the sub items are placed correctly in visible area.